# Power BI connect to rdl file datasource

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, rdl

I am trying to connect power bi to the dataset behind a SSRS report that is saved on Sharepoint. The report is a rdl file. Is it even possible to connect to the data behind the report if I do not know the name of the report server? I tried using the Odata connector but could not get that to work. If anyone has ever done this please let me know how you went about it, because I have spent a lot of time trying to find the name of the report server but have not had any luck.

Thanks so much

Comment: To connect to data in any reporting tool you need the connection information.... which you don't appear to have. Open the RDL in notepad and inspect the data source definition. You certainly can't connect directly to a RDL in Power BI

Comment: The SharePoint admin can tell you which SSRS server it is connected to.